# Is there a way to retrieve the specific parameters used in a random torchvision transform?

Tags: python, pytorch, affinetransform, data-augmentation, torchvision

I can augment my data during training by applying a random transform (rotation/translation/rescaling) but I don't know the value that was selected.

I need to know what values were applied. I can manually set these values, but then I lose a lot of the benefits that torch vision transforms provide.

Is there an easy way to get these values are implement them in a sensible way to apply during training?

Here is an example. I would love to be able print out the rotation angle, translation/rescaling being applied at each image:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision import transforms


RandAffine = transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=0, translate=(0.1, 0.1), scale=(0.8, 1.2))

rotate = transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=45)
shift = RandAffine
composed = transforms.Compose([rotate,
                               shift])

# Apply each of the above transforms on sample.
fig = plt.figure()
sample = np.zeros((28,28))
sample[5:15,7:20] = 255
sample = transforms.ToPILImage()(sample.astype(np.uint8))
title = ['None', 'Rot','Aff','Comp']
for i, tsfrm in enumerate([None,rotate, shift, composed]):
    if tsfrm:
        t_sample = tsfrm(sample)
    else:
        t_sample = sample
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 5, i + 2)
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax.set_title(title[i])
    ax.imshow(np.reshape(np.array(list(t_sample.getdata())), (-1,28)), cmap='gray')    

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy way around it: Torchvision's random transforms utilities are built in such a way that the transform parameters will be sampled when called. They are *unique* random transforms, in the sense that *(1)* parameters used are not accessible by the user and *(2)* the same random transformation is **not** repeatable.

As of Torchvision *0.8.0*, random transforms are generally built with two main functions:

- `get_params`: which will sample based on the transform's hyperparameters (what you have provided when you initialized the transform operator, namely the parameters' range of values)
- `forward`: the function that gets executed when applying the transform. The important part is it gets its parameters from `get_params` then applies it to the input using the associated deterministic function. For [`RandomRotation`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation), [`F.rotate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate) will get called. Similarly, [`RandomAffine`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomAffine) will use [`F.affine`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.affine).

One solution to your problem is sampling the parameters from `get_params` yourself and calling the functional - *deterministic* - API instead. So you wouldn't be using `RandomRotation`, `RandomAffine`, nor any other `Random*` transformation for that matter.

---

For instance, let's look at [`T.RandomRotation`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/d732562f30b8a83af9ab074592af3dd01fe708ee/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py#L1159) (I have removed the comments for conciseness).

```
class RandomRotation(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, degrees, interpolation=InterpolationMode.NEAREST, expand=False, 
        center=None, fill=None, resample=None):
        # ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_params(degrees: List[float]) -> float:
        angle = float(torch.empty(1).uniform_(float(degrees[0]), \
            float(degrees[1])).item())
        return angle

    def forward(self, img):
        fill = self.fill
        if isinstance(img, Tensor):
            if isinstance(fill, (int, float)):
                fill = [float(fill)] * F._get_image_num_channels(img)
            else:
                fill = [float(f) for f in fill]
        angle = self.get_params(self.degrees)

        return F.rotate(img, angle, self.resample, self.expand, self.center, fill)

    def __repr__(self):
        # ...
```

With that in mind, here is a possible override to modify `T.RandomRotation`:

```
class RandomRotation(T.RandomRotation):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomRotation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # let super do all the work

        self.angle = self.get_params(self.degrees) # initialize your random parameters

    def forward(self): # override T.RandomRotation's forward
        fill = self.fill
        if isinstance(img, Tensor):
            if isinstance(fill, (int, float)):
                fill = [float(fill)] * F._get_image_num_channels(img)
            else:
                fill = [float(f) for f in fill]

        return F.rotate(img, self.angle, self.resample, self.expand, self.center, fill)
```

I've essentially copied `T.RandomRotation`'s `forward` function, the only difference being that the parameters are sampled in `__init__` (*i.e.* once) instead of inside the `forward` (*i.e.* on every call). Torchvision's implementation covers all cases, you generally won't need to copy the full `forward`. In some cases, you can just call the functional version pretty much straight away. For example, if you don't need to set the `fill` parameters, you can just discard that part and only use:

```
class RandomRotation(T.RandomRotation):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomRotation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # let super do all the work

        self.angle = self.get_params(self.degrees) # initialize your random parameters

    def forward(self): # override T.RandomRotation's forward
        return F.rotate(img, self.angle, self.resample, self.expand, self.center)
```

---

If you want to override other random transforms you can look at [the source code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py). The API is fairly self-explanatory and you shouldn't have too many issues implementing an override for each transform.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I was afraid that was the answer, but I appreciate your explanation and write up.